# What is the meaning of dimensionless coordinates?

Tags: python, python-xarray

The documentation for the `xarray.DataArray` object [here](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.html) gives this example:

```
<xarray.DataArray (x: 2, y: 2, time: 3)>
array([[[29.11241877, 18.20125767, 22.82990387],
        [32.92714559, 29.94046392,  7.18177696]],

       [[22.60070734, 13.78914233, 14.17424919],
        [18.28478802, 16.15234857, 26.63418806]]])
Coordinates:
    lon             (x, y) float64 -99.83 -99.32 -99.79 -99.23
    lat             (x, y) float64 42.25 42.21 42.63 42.59
  * time            (time) datetime64[ns] 2014-09-06 2014-09-07 2014-09-08
    reference_time  datetime64[ns] 2014-09-05
Dimensions without coordinates: x, y
Attributes:
    description:  Ambient temperature.
    units:        degC
```

I'm confused by the fact that dimensions `x` and `y` don't seem to correspond to `lon` and `lat`.

Wouldn't it make more sense for coordinates `lon` and `lat` to label the `x` and `y` dimensions? It's not clear to me why this example is set up like this.

Comment: You may want to have a look at https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Coordinates.html#xarray.Coordinates to make sure that you're thinking about coordinates the right way.

Comment: Take a closer look at the `lon` and `lat` values. It's not a uniform grid where every row has the same latitude and every column has the same longitude. Every "pixel" has unique values for both coordinates.

Comment: @Brian61354270 Okay, so (ignoring time) we have a 2x2 array of temperatures with dimensions `x` and `y`. Each of the four elements of this array corresponds to a physical location with some combination of `lon` and `lat`. But since `'lon` and `lat` are irregularly spaced, the locations of the four elements do not form a grid and hence the coordinates are not indexable. Is that correct?

Comment: @Estacionario Exactly!

Comment: I plotted the locations of the four array elements. They almost form a square, so I suppose storing them in a 2D array preserves some spatial information independent of the coordinates. I find this example quite a weird way to introduce arrays!